# Where is xpath "element()" documented?

Tags: xslt, xpath, saxon, xslt-3.0, xpath-3.1

I just stumpled upon this xpath function(?) and I assume it is functioning like node(), etc. Hoever, I simply cannot seem to find any documentation.

Example

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="./element()"/>
```

Im using latest version of saxon processor.

Comment: Where else? https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#node-tests

Comment: Also http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/expressions/axissteps.html, as you mention Saxon.

Comment: Note that your assumption that `element()` is comparable to `node()` is correct - but neither is a *function*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, it is documented in the XPath specification. It was introduced in XPath 2.0. In an axis step, and in a pattern, it is (nearly always) equivalent to `*`, but it can also be used as an item type, for example

```
<xsl:if test="$param instance of element()">

<xsl:function name="f:parent" as="element()?">
```